# Blog archives group by month on external webpage

Tags: php, wordpress

i have created this PHP function in wordpress:

```
function show_posts_archive($output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'post' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $page = $wpdb->get_var( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts 
             WHERE post_type= %s 
             group by MONTH(post_date) ", 
            $post_type ) 
        );
    if ( $page )
        return get_post( $page, $output );

    return null;
}
```

how can i display the blog archives (like on a wordpress template) on my external website?

Comment: this may help you http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-web-service/

Comment: Can you be more precise about the expected output? is the resulting page expected to be a count of posts by year/month? Or is it supposed to be the title of the posts ordered by year/month? Or are you expecting something else all together?

Comment: i want to display them like August 2013 | September 2013 | October 2013.... and so on.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you want to display the whole post or just the titles and links of the archive/old items.

But using RSS is probably your best bet (depending on what was used to create the external website)

With permalinks:
    http://example.com/2014/01/feed

and Without permalinks:
    http://example.com/?m=200808&feed=rss2 (personally haven't tested)

You can then parse the RSS and display the information you require, there are quite a few out there, [Zend_Feed](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.feed.html) / [Zend\Feed (Zend Framework2)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.feed.introduction.html) / [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/), all depends on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

**how can i display the blog archives (like on a wordpress template) on my external website?**

Return the posts in an XML format - this would create an RSS - and then get a plugin on your external site to fetch the XML and render them as "posts". This would be the most easiest and logical way, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Probably from your external template you will need to point to the wordpress database. that way you can fetch the details in a query and output it in whichever format you desire.
say August 2013 | September 2013 | October 2013....

I suggest keep database common. Win win situation. Manage both the views independentally